# What happens if a PCI device has so much memory that the BIOS cannot find a fit empty physical address region to assign it to?

Tags: memory, virtual-memory, pci

A 32 bit system can have physical memory of up to 4GiB. right? Oh no, only the virtual address has 4GB limit and because the MMU can add more address bits to the page number, more physical address can be used. For example In sparc32 architecture 4 more bits are added in the page table entry so 16*4GB = 64GB could be used maximum.
In PCI system, the BIOS assigns an offset to BAR(base address register)s so that the memory areas behind a PCI device is seen at certain physical addresses. What if a PCI device has so much memory that it can't be assigned a fit,empty physical region with given maximum 64GB? (or many PCI devices have many areas so that the sum is too big?). Are the address space independent for buses?

Comment: PAE is not available on all 32bit OSes or CPUs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the BIOS can decide what to do: either map just a part of the device, or leave it unmapped and let the device driver in the OS sort it out.

But you are talking about [Physical Address Extension (PAE for short)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension). It helps you to go beyond the 4 GiB limit, with the price that memory management gets more complicated and you won't be able to see all of the memory at the same time: each individual process can have its own memory map, presenting different parts of the 64 GiB physical address space.

If you need to go beyond 64 GiB, it would be theoretically possible to extend the PAE scheme further, but it is really getting to be more trouble than it's worth at that point, so the manufacturers have not done that. It generally makes much more sense to use a 64-bit system architecture at that point.

Comment: “Technically possible” if the CPU manufacturer, chipset manufacturer, and motherboard manufacturer all agreed ;-). Mapping just a part of the device could be understood as mapping part of a memory request, which isn’t possible; I’m not sure how to clarify it without explaining PCI configuration in more detail though. Many large memory devices support(ed) mapping a small window; for GPUs on 32-bit PCs, there was the AGP aperture too.

Comment: Yeah, "theoretically possible" would have been a better word (editing...). Anyway, there is a point where dealing with 4 GiB address space window becomes more trouble than its worth, and at my first guess, 64 GiB is already past that.

Comment: Yeah, from my pov the point where it becomes more trouble than it’s worth is 4GiB ;-).

Comment: Thanks. Just for others' information, the original PCI bus supports 64-bit BAR (combining two BAR registers) to specify 64 bit addressing, so there is no problem in 64 bit system(can use huge memory range in a PCIe device).